# Azure Cognitive Speech Services STT - Partial Text

Tags: speech-recognition, azure-cognitive-services, voice-recognition

In my code (below) when I process it through STT it only gives me the first alphabet/word of the entire audio.

The audio has "A   B    C    D E F"

What am I missing?

```
Imports Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech
Imports Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.SpeechConfig
Imports Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.Audio

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim SpeechConfig As SpeechConfig = FromSubscription("<CHANGED>", "eastus")
        Dim audioConfig As Audio.AudioConfig = Audio.AudioConfig.FromWavFileInput("<CHANGED>.wav")
        SpeechConfig.OutputFormat = Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.OutputFormat.Detailed
        Dim recognizer As New SpeechRecognizer(SpeechConfig, audioConfig)
        Dim result = recognizer.RecognizeOnceAsync().Result

        Select Case result.Reason
            Case ResultReason.RecognizedSpeech
                Console.WriteLine($"RECOGNIZED: Text={result.Text}")
                Console.WriteLine($"    Intent not recognized.")
            Case ResultReason.NoMatch
                Console.WriteLine($"NOMATCH: Speech could not be recognized.")
            Case ResultReason.Canceled
                Dim cancellation = CancellationDetails.FromResult(result)
                Console.WriteLine($"CANCELED: Reason={cancellation.Reason}")

                If cancellation.Reason = CancellationReason.[Error] Then
                    Console.WriteLine($"CANCELED: ErrorCode={cancellation.ErrorCode}")
                    Console.WriteLine($"CANCELED: ErrorDetails={cancellation.ErrorDetails}")
                    Console.WriteLine($"CANCELED: Did you update the subscription info?")
                End If
        End Select

    End Sub

End Module
```

You can download the audio file on github here
https://github.com/ullfindsmit/StackOverflowAssets/blob/master/abcdef.wav

Also, if you know where I could get a more detailed STT data i'd appreciate it.
What I am looking for is like a JSON output that says start time and end time along with the word and/or sentence.

Your help is much appreciated.

**UPDATE**
So The async handlers did not work for me for some reason
However, the code below did

```
        While True
            Dim result = recognizer.RecognizeOnceAsync().Result
            Select Case result.Reason
                Case ResultReason.RecognizedSpeech
                    Console.WriteLine($"RECOGNIZED: Text={result.Text}")
                    Console.WriteLine($"    Intent not recognized.")
                Case ResultReason.NoMatch
                    Console.WriteLine($"NOMATCH: Speech could not be recognized.")
                Case ResultReason.Canceled
                    Dim cancellation = CancellationDetails.FromResult(result)
                    Console.WriteLine($"CANCELED: Reason={cancellation.Reason}")

                    If cancellation.Reason = CancellationReason.[Error] Then
                        Console.WriteLine($"CANCELED: ErrorCode={cancellation.ErrorCode}")
                        Console.WriteLine($"CANCELED: ErrorDetails={cancellation.ErrorDetails}")
                        Console.WriteLine($"CANCELED: Did you update the subscription info?")
                    End If

                    Exit While
            End Select
        End While
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `RecognizeOnceAsync` method will only recognize "once" ... the first "utterance/phrase" contained in the audio data file. If you'd like to recognize more than one phrase, you can do one of these two things:

1. Call `RecognizeOnceAsync` repeatedly... After the last phrase is recognized, the next call to the method will return a result that has `result.Reason` set to `Canceled`.
2. Switch from using `RecognizeOnceAsync` to using `StartContinuousRecognitionAsync` and hook an event hanlder up to the `Recognizing` event. The event callback will allow you to see the results by inspecting the `SpeechRecognitionEventArgs` passed, like this: `e.Result` ...

You can see both of these behaviors by running the Speech CLI like this:

```
spx recognize --once+ --key YOUR-KEY --region YOUR-REGION --file "https://github.com/ullfindsmit/StackOverflowAssets/blob/master/abcdef.wav"
spx recognize --continuous --key YOUR-KEY --region YOUR-REGION --file "https://github.com/ullfindsmit/StackOverflowAssets/blob/master/abcdef.wav"
```

You can download the Speech CLI here: https://aka.ms/speech/spx-zips.zip

Comment: The two event driven options did not work for me. I'll post the updated code in the question